# How to cause deserialization to fail when it's unable to deserialize a value?

Tags: c#, error-handling, json.net

When I serialize and then deserialize a getter-only auto property like this:

```cs
class A {
  public string B { get; }
  private A() { }
  public A(int unusableConstructor) { B = "Val"; }
}
```

Then Json.NET will successfully deserialize the instance of class A by putting "null" into the property B.

But I don't want that!

The trace does contain the message `Unable to deserialize value to non-writable property 'B' on A.` but it's at the `Info` level and the `Error` event doesn't trigger.

Is there a way to convince Json.NET to produce an error in this case or otherwise notify me (other than by attempting to parse the info message from the trace)?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `JsonSerializerSettings` to your `DeserializeObject<T>` method.

Docs [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm).

Example:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
};
var myContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(someString, settings);
```

Comment: Have you checked that? For me it does not throw any errors in the described by OP situation.

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect on my situation. Json.net doesn't consider this inability to deserialize an error or a missing member.

Comment: I'm sorry both, I didn't fully understand the question. The definite answer would be a Custom JsonConverter: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm . I'm not aware if it can be done otherwise!